# Using an URL scheme in XCTestCase

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift, xctest

I want to run a test which awaits the response of a browser.

A test target has an Info.plist where I can register custom URL schemes. But those are never called. I know that an test target is not a real application.

Is there a way?

**EDIT (for bounty):** I want to write an integration test for a class that calls `openUrl("tel://" + some phone number)`. How do I subscribe to this URL scheme in an XCTestCase?

Comment: Are you able to achieve what you need with NSURLProtocol?

Comment: Could you rephrase what you mean by 'subscribe to a URL scheme'? Do you mean, how do you determine which application is assigned to handle a particular scheme? Or do you mean, how do you test whether openURL actually performs the action?

Comment: My application is registered to an URL scheme like this: myapp://. I want to test if I can open http://mywebsite.com in a browser which will redirect to myapp:// eventually.

Answer (score 1):

**The question was retagged to OS X so my answer is no longer valid**

*Original answer*

This is impossible. The basic reason is that the tests are connected to one running application instance, they have no control over the device, they are running as part of the application. You can probably open the URL but you won't be able to return to the application and do an assert.

Also note that XCUnit is a **unit** testing framework. You won't be able to write advanced integration test in it. You might be more successful with UI Automation but this specific test case will be very complicated even for it. For example, to open a link by your app in the simulator, you can create a HTML page that will redirect to the link and then use shell to exec `open testLink.html -a "iOS Simulator"`. However, in my humble opinion this kind of tests is unreliable and realy hard to write and debug.

My advice would be to:

1. Write an unit test that mocks `[UIApplication openURL:]` and verify that you are passing a correct URL to it. Or if you want the other direction, write a unit test that will call `UIApplicationDelegate` methods in the called order, simulating opening a link by your app. This is as far you can go with XCUnit.
2. Test the rest manually.

Comment: My question is about a OS X. I never asked about iOS. But I guess you are right. It is impossible to register a test to an URL scheme.

Comment: @McZonk You have tagged `cocoa-touch`.

Comment: No Loyal Tingley did. However I think the problem will be existent for both platforms.

Comment: @McZonk I don't think so, iOS is very limited compared to OS X. I think there might be a way on OS X. Anyway, I don't think XCUnit is the right tool for it.

Answer (score -1):

I am uncertain what exactly that you are trying to test. I assume that it is something more than whether the URL can be opened or not. The test case below checks whether FaceTime will open and can open a URL. If the app you are testing registers a custom scheme, then simply changing `pathToTestApplication` should work.

[image]

```
class NSURL_SchemeTests: XCTestCase {

    func testWhoHandlesSchemeTel() {
        let testAppURL = NSURL(string: pathToTestApplication)

        // create a NSURL for the test
        let tel = "tel:5555555555"
        let url = NSURL(string: tel)
        XCTAssert(url != nil, "Could not create a URL from \(tel)")

        // determine whether any application is registered to handle the URL
        let workspace  = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
        let urlHandler = workspace.URLForApplicationToOpenURL(url!)
        XCTAssert(urlHandler != nil, "No application found to open URL \(tel)")

        // determine whether the expected test application is registered to handle the URL
        XCTAssert(urlHandler! == testAppURL,
            "Application \(pathToTestApplication) was not registered to handle URL \(tel)")

        // attempt to open the URL
        XCTAssert(workspace.openURL(url!), "Could not open URL \(tel)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to test if my application is successfully registered to an URL scheme and if it gets a callback when myapp:// is opened.

Comment: The test target that this XCT code is a part of will indeed test whether your application is registered to handle the scheme. The last test will also determine whether it successfully communicated with the application.  However if you want to see what your application actually received from the test app, you will have to instrument the application itself.